# Refer to the row that contains the formula in MS Word table

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to create relative references in a Word table, so that the formula for each row reads from the data in a defined column in that row.

Using help pages here as reference
[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-formula-in-a-word-or-outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27#:~:text=it%20is%20ignored.-,RnCn%20references,row%20and%20the%20second%20column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-formula-in-a-word-or-outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27#:%7E:text=it%20is%20ignored.-,RnCn%20references,row%20and%20the%20second%20column).

It says to refer to the row that contains the formula use R... but I don't see examples of that particular reference in the help page - only RnCn style references.

I would like a simple formula in column C to reference the columns in the row in which the formula appears.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 53 | column a - column b |
| 23 | 67 | column a - column b |

I would like to know how to use the "R" reference - as suggested is possible in the help pages - , as opposed to the Rn or RnCn styles. Please could you share an example as I have tried a number of iterations e.g. =RC2, =R(C2) etc and keep getting formatting errors.

My interpretation from the help pages is that RnCn would be absolute references, and that R "the row that contains the formula" is for relative references.

Comment: Word's ability to do relative referencing in tables is severely limited. For an approach you might use, see *Relative Referencing In Tables* in my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, available at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html

Comment: Hi @macropod - apparently your zip file is not available on that forum

Comment: It *most definitely is* available there...

Comment: Thanks @macropod, I've gone back again today and that's now available thank you. That's a great looking doc, though it doesn't refer to the R and C functionalities (as listed on the MS help pages), which are the examples I'm trying to see. 

I don't know if I'm misinterpreting the MS help pages?

Comment: There is an RC addressing feature but AFAICS the help page you referenced has several things wrong with it, e.g. you can't use R on its own to reference the current row, or Rn to reference the nth row, ditto for C and Cn.also the assertion that A1:B2 references "All the cells in the first column and the first two cells in the second column" is wrong (it's actually A1,A2,B1,B2). If anyone has a counter example I'd love to see it.

Comment: For anyone interested, some of the confusion in that MS article may come from the fact that in Word for Windows 2, RnCn addressing was the only kind available, whereas in the next version (6), it was almost entirely replaced by A1-style naming. In Word 2, you *could* do =SUM([R1]) to sum cells in row 1. (You had to have the [ ] around the cell refs.) You could even do {=SUM([R-1])} to sum the preceding row, {=SUM([R-1C+2])}  etc. Even for RnCn notation, there was/is a localization issue, e.g in a German language version of Word {=sum(R1C1,R2C2)} would need to be {=sum(Z1S1;Z2S2)}

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `{=a1-b1}` (using Ctrl + F9 to insert the curly brackets)
[image]

But there is nothing like an Excel-drag-down - you have to write each formula.
Plus: if you insert a row, formulas won't get adjusted!!